# Change default layout when create new product

Tags: magento2, product, layout

When I create a new product, it always selects the layout 1 column.

[image]

Is there any option, I can change the default value of layout when I create new product? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: what layout you want to set for new product?

Comment: I want to set 2 columns left for default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Go To Store -> (Under Attribute) Product
```

Search **page_layout** Attribute.

Set Your Default Layout

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it cand work on default Magento, But it doesn't work on my website. Do you have any idea?

Comment: after changing try to cache clean and then check

Comment: I have changed it to 2 columns left and flush all cache but it still shows 1 column. Do you have any idea?

Comment: no bro... i have no idea for this issue

Comment: Thank you so much Bro!

Comment: happy coding... :)

Comment: Hope your answer can help other people. Thank you and happy coding to you Bro!

Answer (score 0):

Go to configuration > web > default layouts section
It's all described here:
[Magento guide](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/design/page-layout.html)